# Multiple threads writing to same socket causing issues

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I have written a client/server application where the server spawns multiple threads depending upon the request from client.

These threads are expected to send some data to the client(string).

The problem is, data gets overwritten on the client side. How do I tackle this issue ?

I have already read some other threads on similar issue but unable to find the exact solution.

Here is my client code to receive data.

```
while(1)
    {
            char buff[MAX_BUFF];
            int bytes_read = read(sd,buff,MAX_BUFF);
            if(bytes_read == 0)
            {
                    break;
            }
            else if(bytes_read > 0)
            {
                    if(buff[bytes_read-1]=='$')
                    {
                            buff[bytes_read-1]='\0';
                            cout<<buff;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            cout<<buff;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Server Thread code :

```
void send_data(int sd,char *data)
{
    write(sd,data,strlen(data));
    cout<<data;
}

void *calcWordCount(void *arg)
{
    tdata *tmp = (tdata *)arg;
    string line = tmp->line;
    string s = tmp->arg;
    int sd = tmp->sd_c;
    int line_no = tmp->line_no;
    int startpos = 0;
    int finds = 0;
    while ((startpos = line.find(s, startpos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
            ++finds;
            startpos+=1;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&myMux);
            tcount++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMux);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mapMux);
    int t=wcount[s];
    wcount[s]=t+finds;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mapMux);


    char buff[MAX_BUFF];
    sprintf(buff,"%s",s.c_str());
    sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),"%s"," occured ");
    sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),"%d",finds);
    sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),"%s"," times on line ");
    sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),"%d",line_no);
    sprintf(buff+strlen(buff),"\n",strlen("\n"));
    send_data(sd,buff);
    delete (tdata*)arg;
}
```

Comment: Post the server thread code...

Comment: *"The problem is, data gets overwritten on the client side."* - That is highly unlikely.  It is more likely that the "overwritting* is happen on the server side.

Comment: @StephenC Actually, the data from different threads seems to be sent together by TCP causing the issue.

Comment: Why is your code that writes to the buffer and the subsequent call to `send_data()` not protected by a mutex? That's data you depend on to be atomic, is it not?

Comment: yup, but I tried by protecting that call..still no good..

Comment: @Ajit If you care how TCP sends the data, you are doing something terribly wrong. You should be working purely at the application layer and should have no concern for what TCP does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On the server side make sure the shared resource (the socket, along with its associated internal buffer) is protected against the concurrent access.
2. Define and implement an application level protocol used by the server to make it possible for the client to distinguish what the different threads sent.

*As an additional note:* One cannot rely on `read()`/`write()` reading/writing as much bytes as those two functions were told to read/write. It is an essential necessity to check their return value to learn how much bytes those functions actually read/wrote and loop around them until all data that was intended to be read/written had been read/written.

Comment: will an application level protocol help ? bcoz, underlying network protocol will be always TCP which I assume to be causing problem. I feel that since more amount of data can fit into a single TCP segment that the data from each thread.. I am getting the issue.

Comment: I have a different buffer for each thread.. still do I need to protect it ?

Comment: The socket internally has exactly **one** buffer, filled by the calls to `write()`. So **1st protect** the access to the latter. @Ajit

Comment: An application level protocol will certainly help because it will add some additional layers of logic on top of the raw network data that will allow you to determine if you have all the data you need, that it's correct, and where it came from. TCP will ensure your packets are sent and received properly, but not that each packet has what you intended, and that all packet(s) that contain your data set are properly filled out before they are sent.

Comment: TCP delivers the data in exactly the order in which the data had been written to the socket. So if the data is received in mixed-up order, it definitly had been sent in this order by the server.

Comment: pthread_mutex_lock(&thMux);
send_data(sd,buff);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thMux); This is not helping me though.. Writing a application level protocol for such a small assignment.. :(.. Let me try it out.. :)

Comment: The complexity of the protcol depends on the complexity of the data. You did not tell us what the server sends.

Comment: Hey, I made a small change on client side and its working now. It was probably buffer corruption and I was using cout<<buff. I change it to while(i<bytes_read)cout<<buff[i++]; OMG that was so bad.. Well, let me admit that all the suggestion given by you guys are correct considering my data to be large and crossing across the actual n/w. It is working now just bcoz my string are hard 30-40bytes on my localhost... Thanks guys

Comment: @alk, server just send the occurrence of a word in every line. I am formatting the string using sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

You should put some mutex to your socket.

When a thread use the socket it should block the socket.

Some [mutex](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-12/index.html) example.

I can't help you more without the server code. Because the problem is probably in the server.

Comment: I already tried mutex on the write call. But that doesnt work too.. :(