# Lost messages in Multi-thread writting to Socket Outputstream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to write at least 5 messages in the same java socket outputstream, from two different Threads, almost instantaneously.

But to simplify let's say I have two threads writting to the same socket outputstream.
When I write them with more than 1 second interval, I get both messages in the other end, but if I send them below 1 second interval, the first one seems to be overriden(i guess), and only the second one gets the other end.

My writes are performed within a syncronized block:

```
  this.sock =new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hstName), hstPort);
  this.os = this.sock.getOutputStream();  


  synchronized(this.os) {
   this.os.write(buffer, ofset, blen);
   this.os.flush();
  }
```

Anyone knows why my first message is obliterated, whether this is supposed or not, and how can go around this issue.
Notice I can't change the code responsible for receiving the messages. I own the code to send the messages only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are this.os and this.outstream the same variable? could you provide a little bit more info on relevant class? like how you got those fields in the first place, and method itself

Comment: yes it is the same. When I was writing, I was trying to simplify, because this is third party piece of software. Just updated with the lines that create the socket, and assign the os var.

Comment: There is no much more code regarding this question. Of course there is much more code in the application, but the core responsible for writting is this. Hope it can help you to help me.

Comment: Are both writes using the same `buffer`?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. It is not the same buffer.

Comment: could you check if the problem with object that you synchronize on? use some static lock for synchronization, like: ```private static final Object LOCK = new Object();```

Comment: I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167873/multiple-threads-writing-to-same-socket-causing-issues, and somehow I think it is related, but I don't really know if it is the same

Comment: you make "sock" and "os" variables as a class attributes. so the second thread will override the first thread initialization. try to make those variables locally

Comment: This code is within the class used by the the class that creates the threads ( submit()->{]).
The job code is what invokes the method to write. sock and os are not created again, are always the same

Comment: @ramazan, with static lock is the same behaviour.

Comment: Any chance message is lost on the receiver's end? Did you try to write all messages from the same thread?

Comment: I just dont see the message arriving in receiver's end. From the same thread? Not yet. The solution arch forces me to have multiple threads, but I can do the test